# backbone.js - bind or join models from two collections

Tags: backbone.js

I have two datasets returning to two different backbone collections each using a different model. Both models share a field that could be used to link them.

The second ajax call is made after the first has loaded, as a sort of pre-loader.

Upon the second collection being successfully fetched (on 'reset' event), I'd like to somehow bind/join models (or simply copy the JSON in, it's a one way read only thing) with the same value for the common field to a property on each of the other models where there is a match.

Just re-read that and I don't think it reads very well, but hopefully you understand...

Collection 1

```
[
  {
    foo: 'text',
    bar: 'xxx'
  },
  {
    foo: 'text',
    bar: 'yyy'
  }
]
```

Collection 2

```
[
  {
    prop1: 'a',
    prop2: 'b',
    bar: 'xxx'
  }
]
```

Whether the raw data is added or a binding established, I desire the collection 1 JSON to be able to read like this

```
[
  {
    foo: 'text',
    bar: 'xxx',
    prop1: 'a',
    prop2: 'b',
  },
  {
    foo: 'text',
    bar: 'yyy'
  }
]
```

Or

```
[
  {
    foo: 'text',
    bar: 'xxx',
    extraProps: {
      prop1: 'a',
      prop2: 'b'
    }
  },
  {
    foo: 'text',
    bar: 'yyy'
  }
]
```

Any help greatly appreciated. All the ways I'm thinking it could be achieved don't seem very *backboney*

PS: I've just noticed a backbone-relational tag while tagging this question. I'll have a read there and post back if I see anything useful. It's quite a hard question for form a good search phrase for...

**EDIT**

Thanks for the replies, I popped away to write a quick script and noticed that I had some replies before I'd even finished. Anyway, just for reference I will add my initial, perhaps quite bodgy script. Please ignore the fact that mailing/mailing_id don't have the same field name, I am not in control of the data sources at this time...

```
<script>
var matches = 0;
_.each(clicks.models, function(click) {
  _.each(mailshots.models, function(mailshot){
    if(click.get('mailing') == mailshot.get('mailing_id')){
      matches++;
      click.set('subject',mailshot.get('mailing_subject'));
    }
  });
});
if(matches) clicks.trigger('reset');
</script>
```

Anyway, that works. But I'm just going to test the first reply and have a glance at backbone-relational. Might be more than I need now but looks interesting...

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational). Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Just taking a look now, looks more powerful than I need for my fairly simple use case. But I'll certainly have a play with it.

Comment: I've just had a look at backbone-relational. It looks pretty helpful and powerful but isn't appropriate for this simple read only report style app. Thanks for pointing it out though, I thought the tag was about a principle as opposed to a library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when the two collections have been loaded you can do something like this

```
_(collection2).each(function(v,i){
 var model = collection1.where({bar:v.get("bar")}).first();// assuming values of bar are unique
 model.set("prop1",v.get("prop1"));
 model.set("prop2",v.get("prop2"));
})
```

and to be more dynamic

```
 _(collection2).each(function(v,i){
     var model = collection1.where({bar:v.get("bar")}).first();// assuming values of bar are unique
     _.each(_.keys(v),function(k){
          model.set(v,v.get(k));
        });
})
```

Comment: Hi Parv, thank for the reply. I definitely like the idea of copying all keys across (although maybe looping through a white-listed fields array, just in case). I'm getting an error when trying to use .first() where the .where() doesn't return any results, which is breaking the loop before it finds some matches. I could wrap it up in a check, but I guess the where is just an alias for the code I've added in my question edit. What do you think?

Comment: i have used where because its provided directly by the backbone js.. and yses i was assuming that values are present so yes you can do a check before taking first